the Volume of Parallelepiped Spanned by (1,-1,2), (a,1,-1), (-1,2,2) is 1 for a=?
The volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors $(1,-1,2)$, $(a,1,-1)$, and $(-1,2,2)$ is equal to $1$ for what value of $a \in \mathbb{R}$?
I've tried solving for the determinant of this 3x3 matrix, and I got $a =-2/3$. However, according to the solution, the answer should be $a = -1$. I'm not sure how the solution gets that, any help would be appreciated

Your answer is also correct, for what it's worth. Hint: absolute value

Please type your question into the body as images cannot be searched.  Alpha gets $6a+5$ for the determinant.

Where should i put the absolute value? And why? @user170231

@RossMillikan yeah 6a+5=1. Solving for a, we get a =-2/3

$6a+5=|1|$ leads to two roots. First, $6a+5=1$ then $a=-2/3$. Again, $6a+5=-1$, then $a=-1$. We can consider both values here.

@M.Riyan I think you mean $|6a+5|=1$.

@Arthur Yes, this is it.

See the formulas here, and explanation for the absolute value here (ctrl+F "Why do we need the absolute value?")

Another way to understand the absolute value: The determinant flips sign if two rows/columns are exchanged, but changing the order of the vectors can't change the parallelipiped spanned by them. (It technically changes the orientation but that really should be immaterial in this context.) So we have to suppress any overall minus sign to get a meaningful result.
